# Top layout guide mismatch

Tags: ios, interface, interface-builder

Top of the grey UIView should be constrained to bottom of the top layout guide, but it's obviously not.

[image]

The grey view is nothing but a container view as can be seen in Interface Builder below. I should have added the child view correctly; however, childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false causes the child view to not appear at all. Could this be the cause?

```
//        childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addChildViewController(dayExpenseVC)
    dayExpenseVC.view.frame = childView.frame

    childView.addSubview(dayExpenseVC.view)
    dayExpenseVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a frame vs bounds issue.

I solved it by doing this:

```
dayExpenseVC.view.frame = childView.bounds
```

The frame of childView was offset from its parent view and assigning that to the frame of dayExpenseVC also offset it by the same amount from its parent view, which is the childView.